# Chromium is constantly changing URL

Tags: google-chrome, url, url-rewriting

This is probably a desired behavior, but it annoys me a lot lately. 
I'm developing some software and need to send some requests to the server. 
When I type in for example `https://myserver/rest/part1/part2`, I get 404. That's fine because I've probably typed something wrong. But the Chromium automatically changes the URL to `https://myserver/rest/part1` or something else, which might also give 404. Why does Chromium rewrite the URL? I need to get the get parameters from different sources and I'm making mistakes a lot, but when google rewrites the URL, **I loose the parameters which I've typed in**. I assume there's some "clever" algorithm which changes the URL to some similar which was OK at some point in the past in case of 404.

Is there some way to disable this obnoxious behavior? I see no use case for this "feature". 
Also it would be nice if Chromium didn't come up with a google search when I type "myserver.com" instead of accessing that URL. What's even more puzzling is that this also happens when I include port. Constantly writing `https://` gets old pretty quickly. This is also bad, but not as bad as URL rewriting.

Here's a screencast: https://vimeo.com/374638699

Comment: Does it happen only with Chromium? Have you looked into Developer Tools, Network tab? For me it sounds like the server is requesting a redirect.

Comment: There's no redirect, but now I see that the problem might be also when server responds 204. I've noticed this doesn't happen when I use the "mistyped" URL in new browser window. Problem starts when I try to edit the URL. In the response header, there's just date, but the URL in chromium changes.

Comment: I've added a screencast

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the link.